# How to create UIView programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiview

How to create UIView programmatically?

Comment: @livingtech that suggested question doesn't seem to me to have anything to do with this question.

Comment: No kidding. I don't even remember reading this question yesterday, much less commenting on it. Now I just have to find the question that comment was supposed to relate to...

Comment: in Swift: `let view = UIView()`

Answer (score 1):

Typically something like this:

```
UIView* myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
// View setup
[mySuperview addSubview:myView];
```

[Apple's UIView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview) will help you.